# What is the difference between React component’s phases and React component’s life cycle?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

What is the difference between  React component’s phases and  React component’s life cycle?

Answer (score 1):

Basically all the React component’s lifecyle methods can be split in four phases: initialization, mounting, updating and unmounting.

The initialization phase is where we define defaults and initial values for this.props and this.state by implementing getDefaultProps() and getInitialState() respectively.

Mounting phase has two methods that we can hook up with: componentWillMount() and componentDidMount().

When a component’s state or properties get updated. the lifecycle methods are part of the updating phase.

Unmounting phase includes componentDidMount()/componentDidUpdate()